# Ruby on Rails: Creating new model in nested association with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-forms, has-many

So I have an issue where a user needs to be able to place an `order`, each order is made up of one of more `pizza_order` models. A `pizza_order` has a polymorphic relationship with a `pizza` model in that it can either point to an entry in the `specials` table which has a pre-defined list of toppings, or it can point to an entry in the `pizzas` table, at which point the user can choose the crust type and toppings.

I had previously solved the issue of trying to create multiple `pizza_order` entries in one `order` by using the Cocoon gem, and that works fine. It even works fine when each `pizza_order` is only associated with an entry from `specials` table. Once I try to get the custom pizza entry to work things start breaking.

This is what a new `order` will look like

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :pizza_orders do |pi_order| %>
    <%= render partial: 'pizza_order_fields', locals: {f: pi_order}%>
  <% end%>
  <div class="add-field">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Pizza', f, :pizza_orders, id: "add_btn", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <%= f.submit "Place Order", class: "btn btn-primary "%>
<% end %>
```

Whenever the user pressed 'Add Pizza' this will render a new partial to pick either a specialty, or custom pizza. That form looks like this

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="form-inline">
  <legend>Specialty Pizzas</legend>
  <% @specials.each do |sp| %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= f.label :pizza_id, sp.get_name_and_cost %>
      <%= f.radio_button :pizza_id, sp.id %>
      <h5>Crust Type:  <%= sp.pizza.crust.name %></h5>
      <h5>Toppings:
      <% sp.pizza.toppings.each do |top| %>
          <%= top.name + (top == sp.pizza.toppings.last ? "" : ",") %>
      <% end %>
      </h5>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= f.label "Custom" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :pizza_id, "Custom", id: "custom_pizza" %>
    <div id="custom_pizza_fields">
      <%= f.fields_for :pizza_id do |pi| %>
          <%= render partial: 'custom_pizza', locals: {pi: pi} %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<%= f.label :quantity %>
<%= f.number_field :quantity, class: "number_field" %>
<br/>
<%= link_to_remove_association "Delete", f , id: "delete_btn", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<hr/>
```

Finally this renders a partial to create a custom pizza, which looks like this

```
<h5>Crust Type</h5>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <% Crust.all.each do |crust| %>
        <td>
          <%= pi.label :crust, crust.name %>
          <%= pi.radio_button :crust, crust.id %>
        </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
<h5>Toppings</h5>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <% Topping.all.each do |topping| %>
        <td>
          <%= pi.label :toppings, topping.get_name_and_cost %>
          <%= pi.check_box :toppings %>
        </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm fairly certain the problem is coming from this 2nd `fields_for` line, which reads `<%= f.fields_for :pizza_id do |pi| %>`. Unlike the specialty pizza, which already exist in the database, custom pizzas will be created when the user places the order. So I don't think `:pizza_id` will map to anything at this point.

Another issue is how do I return a collection of `Toppings` to map to the `has_many` field in the `pizza` model? I have implemented checkboxes, but I can't verify whether this will return a collection since my previous problem is halting further progress at the moment.

For reference, here are the models being used.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pizza_orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pizza_orders
end

class PizzaOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pizza, allow_destroy: true
end

class Special < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  validates :pizza, :presence => true
  validates :cost, :presence => true

  def get_name_and_cost
    "#{pizza.name}: $#{cost}"
  end
end

class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :toppings
  has_many :pizza_orders, as: :pizza
  belongs_to :crust
  validates :crust, presence: true
end

class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizzas

  def get_name_and_cost
    "#{self.name}: $#{self.cost}"
  end
end

class Crust < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizzas
end
```

One last thing. This is how I plan on handling strong-typed parameters for the order, but I'm not too sure if it is accurate

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:cost, pizza_orders_attributes: [:quantity, pizza_attributes: [:crust, :toppings]])
end
```

Comment: There were no errors when I made this question. I'm fairly new at Rails an was wondering the best approach for generating a form that would potentially make many new models upon submission. I managed to make some changes and think I'm on a better path though. I changed the checkbox line to be `<%= check_box_tag "pizza[toppings][]", topping.id %>` and now the only error I'm getting is `Unpermitted parameter: toppings`. My parameters look like this `params.require(:order).permit(:cost, pizza_orders_attributes: [:quantity, :pizza_id, :_destroy]) params.require(:pizza).permit(:crust, :toppings)`